# Error with composer update does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have this error when i run composer update

Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\AdvancedPayment located in C:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago\Entities\AdvancedPayments\AdvancedPayment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

how is it solved?

Comment: conseguiste resolverlo?

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not strange that MercadoPago is so horrible developed...

You cannot use that package (at least as PSR4), because the file namespace is `MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments` but it is located in `MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/AdvancedPayments.php` so that is not PSR4 compliant...

If you check their [`composer.json`](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php/blob/5b7e2e7ad87f957d712db0bc7cd84b3b1b20ffe0/composer.json#L28-L38) file, you will see that the PSR4 is a little weird... I never saw PSR4 defined in composer that way...

Comment: any possible solution?

Comment: @gepex from my understanding, not really.